# How to convert tensor to one hot shape?

Tags: pytorch, one-hot-encoding

I am a beginner of using Pytorch, and I have many problems in using it.
I loaded Images as size [3240, 1, 512, 512], and these images have 3labels each. So I want to convert image size to [3240, 3, 512, 512].

**My Code**:
`y_train_h = F.one_hot(y_train, num_classes=3)`

**Result**:
*RuntimeError: one_hot is only applicable to index tensor.*

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested yet but you can try and verify it:

```
y_train_h = torch.zeros(3240,3,512,512)
y_train_h[y_train.long()] = 1
```

Comment: I tried your code, it doesn't work. I think the problem is `y_train_h`. 
`y_train_h = F.one_hot(y_train, num_classes=3)` when I run this code, it come out with the **RuntimeError**. 
How to use `torch.nn.functional.one_hot` function?

Comment: What is the RuntimeError? Can you show it? @Code_B

Comment: What I faced error code is this:
"RuntimeError: one_hot is only applicable to index tensor."

Comment: @Code_B No, please. The code I wrote above is what you need from `one_hot` function. Use my code only.

Comment: For better understanding, I have modify my answer a bit @Code_B

Comment: Oh I See... I understood. Let me try it again! It may takes time a bit..

Comment: OMG, It really takes lots of time..! I wondering it is woking well or not.. haha..

Comment: Now it works, right? @Code_B

Comment: It works and it's running, but it's still running.. not finished..

Comment: I solved this problem using another way, using `scatter()` function. thx for your help!